# Regex en Laravel 8

Tags: php, regex

estoy aprendiendo a usar Laravel 8 y tengo la duda sobre la validación con REGEX. Actualmente estoy recibiendo algunos inputs y que pueden tener un formato similar a este:

Calz. Vallejo Mz. 45

Al revisar la documentación de laravel, alpha y alpha_num no me funcionan ya que el posible valor de la cadena introducida por el usuario lleva espacios y puntos. Trate con el siguiente regex, pero al momento solo me marca error.

```
regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u
```

Alguna idea de como puedo validar este input?.

Comment: prueba con alpha_dash

Answer (score 0):

Buen, tras tratar con diferentes soluciones, logre que se validara con el siguiente regex: `'regex:/^.*$/i`